# Check if email id exists in facebook account

Tags: php, facebook, email-verification

I have a requirement. I want to have a verifier( i am using PHP) which takes the email id as input and verifies that whether there is any facebook account which exists with that email id or not. I am OK to use any APIs if available.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do that using Facebook Graph API 
[Check this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api#search)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors','Off');
$account = 'enter email';

set_time_limit(0);
/*GET CONTENT BY FACEBOOK GRAPH*/
$search = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/search?q={$account}&type=user"));

if($search->id)
{
    echo "yes";
}
else 
{
    echo "no";      
}
?>
```

Comment: this does not work, you can´t search for users by email

Comment: It gives "no" for all. I just ran the url in browser. Following is the return. {
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104,
      "fbtrace_id": "EZ2dkdzkwIG"
   }
}

Comment: @vikram : Check how to use Graph API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api#search

Comment: of course you need a token. but even with a token, you can´t search for users by email. it´s just not possible. this answer is wrong, i´m afraid.